# Using STL to search for raw bytes and replace it in a file, what is the best / correct way

Tags: c++, stl, c++11

I'd like to use the STL (C++0x in vs2010) to open a file and binary search through it and then replace when a match is found.

I can use fstream to open a file but i'm a bit confused to how to search the file.

Reading one byte at a time isn't good so it should read a block into a buffer and we then search in the buffer but is this functionality already in the STL ?

I want the buffering part to be automatic, when the search reach the end of buffer it should automatically read in the next block from the file as if it was reading it directly (using the same file offsets, etc..)

The other problem is when it finds a match exactly how should it update the file.

I know that this file functionality exists in windows using CreateFileMapping and [MapViewOfFile](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa366761%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) but i want to use the STL to make my code portable and also by using the STL also more flexible. Using these windows function you can read the file without worrying about buffering, etc, they will even update the file when you change data. This is the functionality i'm after using the STL.

**Update**: I've changed 'binary search' to 'raw byte search' to clear up the confusion, sorry for that.

An example of the raw byte search function ( **if you have a better please do tell** )

```
// NOTE: This function doesn't support big files > 4 gb
DWORD_PTR RawByteSearch( PBYTE pBaseAddress, DWORD dwLowSize, PBYTE pSignature, DWORD sigSize )
{
 PBYTE pBasePtr = pBaseAddress;
 PBYTE pEndPtr = pBaseAddress + dwLowSize;
 DWORD_PTR i;
 while ( pBasePtr < pEndPtr )
 {
  for (i = 0; i < sigSize; ++i)
  {
   if ( pSignature[i] != pBasePtr[i] )
    break;
  }
  if ( i == sigSize ) // Found a match
  {
   return pBasePtr - pBaseAddress;
  }
  ++pBasePtr; // Next byte
 }
 return 0;
}
```

Comment: The buffering logic you're describing is usually best done with platform-specific features (on Linux it's called mmap).  Can you elaborate on what specifically you want to find and replace in the file?  Is the file guaranteed to be sorted, and, if so, are you sure it's safe to replace the bytes without re sorting the data?

Comment: So, you are replacing a sequence of bytes with a sequence of the same size? It could be done with `iostream`, but is definitely more involved, the key thing is that the sequence size has to be the same, if the size changes, then you have a problem...

Answer (score 3):

`std::search` already does what you need.

```
std::search(pBasePtr, bEndPtr, pSignature, pSignature+sigSize)
```

Out of completeness, you don't need to use memory mapping (although that will likely be the most efficient).

A 100% portable solution is to instead use the standard library stream iterators:

```
std::ifstream file;
std::search(std::istreambuf_iterator<char>(file.rdbuf()) // search from here
          , std::istreambuf_iterator<char>()             // ... to here
          , pSignature                                   // looking for a sequence starting with this
          , pSignature+sigSize);                         // and ending with this
```

Comment: Wow, that's really cool. Thanks for istreambuf_iterator, I didn't know about its existence.

Comment: there is also `std::istream_iterator`. The difference is that a streambuf iterator works on the underlying buffer (so it isn't affected by formatting), whereas a stream iterator works with the stream itself, so it iterates over the output of the stream itself (where, for example, whitespace is removed). So in general, I find stream iterators to be fairly useful. streambuf iterators are handy, but keep in mind they're much slower than you're used to with iterators, because they wrap a `std::stream`, which has quite a bit of overhead.

Comment: I'm not sure why but this causes the program to crash with error
"istreambuf_iterator is not dereferencable"

Comment: well, if you copied my exact code, then it's because `file` isn't initialized correctly. I never tell it which file to open. :)

Comment: Oh, I'm not sure if that's what you're seeing, but I just realized that the code won't actually work. `std::search` expects its arguments to be forward iterators, but the stream iterators are only input iterators, so they're missing features that `search` relies on.

Comment: This use of std::search with std::istreambuf_iterator compiles with gcc/libstdc++, but it fails to compile with clang/libc++, exactly because the iterator requirements aren't satisfied.

Answer (score 2):

You should avoid the term "binary search". This is a term used for searching in sorted data in logarithmic time, what you are doing is a linear search (in binary data). The C++ standard library has a function for that, it's std::search. It would work something like:

```
PWORD pos = std::search(pBaseAddress, pBaseAddress+dwLowSize, pSignature, pSignature+pSigSize);
```

P.S. Hungarian Notation sucks ;)

Comment: Yes i knew that but i could come up with a better name for it. Do you have a suggestion of what to call it, i mean i can't call it text search since it's not text i'm searching for.

Comment: I have change it to raw byte search for the time being

Answer (score 0):

BinarySearch actually means starting at the midway point and comparing to slice your search space in two, then going to the midway point of the new search space to divide it further. As your search space halves with every iteration, the operation is O(log N) which is therefore in general a lot faster.

You may wish to do that here by building up an index.

A lot of this depends how your file is formatted. Does it consist of fixed-length "records" with a key at the start of the record and with that key sorted?

If so, you can actually scan every Nth record to create an index in memory, then use binary search to locate where approximately in the file the record would be, then load just that section of the file into memory.

For example, let's say each record is 128 bytes, the key is 4 bytes and there are 32K records, so the file is about 4MB big. If you load every 64th record, you are reading 512 of them and storing 2K of data in memory. When you search your local index you then load an 8K portion into memory and search in that for the actual record you wish to change, and modify it appropriately.

If your records are not all the same length, you will have a problem if your modification tramples over the next record.

Answer (score 0):

std::fstream has a function called *read* that can read a block into a buffer. Am I misunderstanding something?

Edit: I just did a quick search on memory-mapped file implementations. Maybe this can be helpful for you:
http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_40_0/libs/iostreams/doc/classes/mapped_file.html

Comment: If I understand the question correctly, the OP wants to use memory mapping rather than read the data explicitly.

Comment: This probably sounds very naive, correct me if I misunderstood the problem, if I was asked to solve a problem like this, my initial program would read in the file in blocks of X bytes using std::fstream and I will use a _sliding window_ to attempt to match the pattern.

Comment: Well it doesn't have to be memory mapped, as long so it's efficient i'm ok with what ever works best. As long as i can search for a byte array and if match found, replace it with another and update the file.

Comment: I just want it to be efficient, fast and support above 4 gb files (just in case)

Comment: Do you have any specific performance requirements? By efficient do you mean find a byte string in sub-second time? What about the size of search patterns? Any assumptions we can make? Are they going to be small (byte, 1K) or quite big (megs/gigs)?

Comment: no performance requirements. The size of the search pattern will depend on how common the byte string is so the more common it is the bigger the search pattern need to be to find the one i'm looking for. I probably should tell you that this byte string is machine code instructions, if that will help you help me.